# Testing for uniformity/skew of ordinal data

Tags: distributions, python, skewness

**Setting:** I have a large sample of posts made by politicians on social media. I know the topic of each of these posts (40 possible topics), and I know how popular each of the topics were compared to each other (in terms of likes and some other measures) at the time of posting. If politicians are completely unaffected by how popular a given topic is when deciding to make a new post about some topic, then you would expect to see a random draw from the ranking of topics (ie. they would be just as likely to make a post about the least popular topic [ranked 40] as they would be to make a post about the most popular topic [ranked 1] - or any other intermediate topic on the ranking). It turns out that they are slightly more inclined to make posts about topics in the top 15 - hence, the distribution is skewed towards the left (ie. the high rankings: 1, 2, 3.. etc.). However, I don't know if this skew is significant.

**My question:** How can I test if this distribution is indeed skewed? I believe that I want to test if the distribution is different from a discrete uniform distribution of ordinal variables (ie. 1 is closer to 2 than it is to 3), which per definition has a skew of 0 (Pearson's moment coefficient of skewness). However I don't know which test to use. If the variables had been categorical, then I suppose I could have used a chi-squared test. Or if the expected distribution had been Gaussian I could have used [this Python implemented "skewtest" which is only sparsely described in the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewtest.html).